# ListView solo agrega un elemento

Tags: android, xamarin, listview

estoy declarando y agregando datos a un listview en Xamarin Android, pero a pesar de que le añado 4 datos sólo me muestra 1, lo declaro de esta manera:

```
        list = new List<String>();
        list.Add("Dato 1");
        list.Add("Dato 2");
        list.Add("Dato 3");
        list.Add("Dato 4");

        lista = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lista);

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);
        lista.SetAdapter(adapter);
```

y aquí declaro mi ListView en el layout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="800px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60px">
            <ListView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lista"
                android:textColor="#F0EEEE" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Alguna idea de por qué me muestra sólo un elemento en el listView??

Comment: Podrías agregar todo tu Layout Erik?

Comment: Si claro, ya lo actualicé

Comment: necesitas para algo el margen abajo de 60 px ?

Comment: Mmmm en realidad no, sólo era para que no quedara a borde de la pantalla

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`,aunque te recomendaría sacarlo del lineal layout si no vas a integrar mas elementos

Comment: te recomiendo esos wrap_content que tienes en los heigth a math_parent. Tal vez lo que este ocurriendo es que la lista en cuestion no tiene suficiente espacio para crecer y mostrar todos los elementos de la lista. Y como tienes un minHeigh/width entonces te da el tamano suficiente para solo un elemento.

Comment: Creo que encontré el problema, lo que pasa es que en ese layout debo poner varios elementos, por lo cual usé un scrollview, peroo esto hace que en mi listview sólo me muestre un elemento, intenté sacar el listview del scroll pero me lo oculta y no me muestra nada de  la lista.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu sugerencia, creo que encontré el problema, lo que pasa es que en ese layout debo poner varios elementos, por lo cual usé un scrollview, peroo esto hace que en mi listview sólo me muestre un elemento, intenté sacar el listview del scroll pero me lo oculta y no me muestra nada de la lista.

Comment: ah, la solucion es facil. Si requieres tener un scroll view con una lista adentro debes ponerle la propiedad android:fillViewport="true" al scrollView. Con eso debe solucionarte el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Yo pude haciendo lo siguiente.

Como al tener el `ListView` dentro del `ScrollView`, el `ListView` se ajustaba el tamaño de su primer item, cree CustomListView.

**CustomListView.cs**

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public CustomListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(int.MaxValue >> 2, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

**Main.axml**

cambia el namespace al de tu proyecto.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ScrollView              
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Namespace.CustomListView
              android:minWidth="25px"
              android:minHeight="25px"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/lista"
              android:textColor="#F0EEEE" />
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

y declare y agrege los datos a al `ListView` como lo hizo usted. Solo edite la ultima linea.

```
    var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Dato 1");
        list.Add("Dato 2");
        list.Add("Dato 3");
        list.Add("Dato 4");

        var lista = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lista);

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);
        lista.Adapter = adapter;
```

Espero que sirva. En este caso se van a mostrar todos los items del `ListView`